# How to cite a Matlab function

Tags: citations

I want to cite `polyfit` function described in : https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html

How can I cite it? Specially in bibtex format?

I don't know if I should point to the URL or use MATLAB trademark and the software version...

Comment: By the way, I suggest that you [don't use any trademark symbols](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/61852/958), and that you [write Matlab rather than MATLAB](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/44638/958).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `polyfit` is a basic Matlab function, you could reference the Matlab Function Reference book (pdf) for the version of Matlab you are using. It would be appropriate to reference the page number of were the function is decsribed in your text. The manual is easily added as a book. The references can be found on the [Mathworks web](https://se.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, however I have problem  to open your second link. Wish you put them in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are only interested in the algorithm and not in its specific implementation in Matlab, consider citing an article or a textbook that describes it, rather than its implementation. In your case, for instance, `polyfit` does least-squares polynomial fitting (with a fixed degree), which you can find described in many textbooks.

Comment: +1. Citing and disclosing the method (and its parameters) is fundamental, and often more important than citing MATLAB's documentation. Also do provide the MATLAB version.